# Paste code in html editor

Tags: asp.net, editor, tinymce-4

I need a tool where I can paste code and view it on a web page.
I tried TinyMCE 4.x. It works fine, but I found one problem: Indentation is not kept when I paste code from Visual Studio. I googled, but I cant find a solution to that,
I tried fckeditor a couple of months ago. I has a syntax highlighter, but if I recall correctly, it had the same problem with indentation.

I need the tool to help me with three things:
Write plain text
Paste code mainly from Visual Studio
Upload image

Most of the google hits are from 2009-2010, so what do I use 2013?
Should I abandon the 'famous' editors and go for something in this 4 year old article: 
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/

Im building this with asp.net 4.5

Or maybe just sum it up with one question: How did you get this kind of requirement up & running?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want also to try other text editors like **ckeditor** (references: http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor, http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), you may also like to use **nicEdit** which I'm also using right now (http://nicedit.com/), or you may want to use **WYSIWYM Markdown Editor[wmd]** (https://github.com/derobins/wmd, http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) like this one on stack overflow.. And another one **Rich Text Editor [RTE]** (demo is here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm, main site is here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/).

Comment: I haven't tested all that editors and I dont know if it will meet your need but perhaps its worth a try. Maybe it could help you. :)

Comment: Hi 
Thank you for sharing your ideas.
I just realised that I can use Alt when I copy code from visual studio. Indentation is kept. I will give this a try for a while.